# How to fetch "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK" issue in VS Code [Windows 11]?

Tags: avd-manager

VS Code is giving the error "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK" on entering create android emulator path.

I tried to create an android emulator on vs code, but it is giving the error "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK" so I am not able to proceed ahead.